# how to exclude jQuery checkbox results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I picked up some code and it works fine, but I need one more function.
If I get a result which contains A and B, the result from A only and B only should be hidden again.

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function () {
    $("div").hide();
    $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daego/bgfy56oz/9/

Comment: As per your code,condition is either categorya or categoryb you have to hide div.

Comment: Please Check http://jsfiddle.net/bgfy56oz/10/

Answer (score 1):

You can append a string with your selected checkbox and run them as selector.

Code:

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function () {
    $("div").hide();
    var mySel='';
    $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        mySel+='.'+$(this).val();
    });

    $(mySel).show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ht4zs1y/

Comment: is it possible to remove the CSS complete ?  cause i have over 50 categorys and i must write it in html AND css,  thats to much, only thing that is important is "display:none;"  so at the beginning the page is clear.      Fork here  http://jsfiddle.net/daego/6ht4zs1y/19/

Comment: You need an attribute to filter on alternatively use a component like isotope: isotope.metafizzy.co. If you refactor your code eventually open a new question

Comment: sry i just ask because i found a similar code here   http://jsfiddle.net/daego/Ddnuh/977/   there is no CSS, different code of course but also no "exlude"

Comment: @TheProfessorJenkins is the same code, can you expand what you mean with no CSS please?

Comment: the 977 has no CSS code (what i want) , but there is the problem again that A and B and AB is shown when i select AB. A and B should be hidden there

Comment: yes, but now when i uncheck all boxes, the list is visible again ?!

Comment: thats perfect THX ! when i am done i post what i made out of this.